# In Excel, how do you count a blank cell in a column if an adjacent column has a certain value?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm working on a Headcount forcasting spreadsheet. The left column has the groups and then the positions that have been requisitioned. Columns to the right of this column are for each month. As the positions are approved they are given an id number, then when it is filled the id is replaced with a name. I want to be able to create totals at the bottom of the worksheet for each position and each group. I was trying a SumProduct but it is not working.

Example:

```
    Groups (ColumnA)                  September(ColumnC)
    Admin - Admin                     228-1
    Admin - Admin                     Sam Jones
    Admin - Admin                     
    Admin - Met Data Analyst          John Smith
    Sales - Business Dev              
    Sales - Coordinator 
    MinPro - Technician               229-1
    MinPro - Technician               
    MinPro - Technician
```

The formula I tried using is: =SUMPRODUCT(--(A5:A6=A120),--(C5:C6<>""))

A120 = Admin - Admin down near the bottom where my totals section is.
I was hoping that this would tell me 2 position approved in September but it just returns 0. Similarly it should then show that We've asked for 3 Technicians in MinPro and so 1 has been approved.

I would then do a similar count to count the ones that have been requisition but not approved yet.

I was also trying to do it with CountIfs but it was doing what I was hoping for.
Hopefully that makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I've done this before but I'm drawing blanks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry it says 'black', but I meant to say blank...my bad.

Comment: Your formula is fine - I suggest a problem with the data, perhaps neither of A5 or A6 is exactly equal to A120? Are there any leading/trailing spaces in any of those 3 cells - that would mean you wouldn't get a match - COUNTIFS alternative would be `=COUNTIFS(A5:A10,A120,C5:C10,"<>")` but that will also founder depending on data......

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a result a bit like this...

[image]

Then the functions you require are...

**Top Table**

Column C IsBlank function: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),1,0)

Column D Is Not Blank function: =IF(ISBLANK(B2),0,1)

**Summary (Bottom Table)**

A unique list of the things in column a from your original data in Column A

Column B function: =SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,$A15,$C$2:$C$10)

Column C function: =SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,$A15,$D$2:$D$10)

These could maybe be combined into less functions but essentially you want a raw data table with a function to determine blankness and a summary table that sumif's the results of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with a PivotTable (and an extra column):

[image: SO12640869 example]

`Groups (ColumnA)` for ROWS, and again with `September(ColumnC)` for VALUES (Count of).